# How to make the basic jar's' to an excutable jar?

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Hi all,

I have about 10 jars and when I run my program I invoke the following:

```
java -Xmx1024m -cp a.jar;b.jar;c.jar;whatever.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 [package][class]
```

I want to make this as an executable jar. I thought that when I `unjar` (that sounds weird, but I'm using java command - not using general zip program) the jar containing `[package][class]`, update `manifest.mf` and rejar it. Unfortunately, this did not work.

Is it possible for me to make it as an executable `jar` or I should unjar it and sum it all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [java eclipse create executable jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8159046/java-eclipse-create-executable-jar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need this line in your manifest file

```
Main-Class: my.package.Main
```

Then run the `jar` command with the `m` flag, and give it the name of your manifest file:

```
jar cmf manifest main.jar *.class
```

Unfortunately, jars can't contain other jars. Give the jar containing your entry point a `Main-Class`, and then set the classpath so that the other 9 jars are accessible.

Comment: Uh. I heard that -cp doesn't work with -jar command.. Is that right? How about putting line 'Class-Path: a.jar b.jar c.jar ~~~ 'in the manifest file? (By the question author)

Comment: I want to add +1 for Andrew Thompson - Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Jar is a collection of files. To make a jar an executable the most important thing is that it should contain a class that has the **main()** method. So, you can make a jar executable only if contains a .class file that has a main method. That class will look like this.

```
public class AClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ...
    }jar 
       ...
}
```

Then and only then can you make a jar executable.

If the main() method class is present. Then to make the jar executable do this.

1. Extract the jar
2. In the manifest file add this line `Main-Class:AClass` and don't forget to press `enter` after this line. follow this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)
3. Rejar the class files. You got the executable jar now

To execute the jar, (suppose you made a.jar executable), then run `java -jar a.jar` to run the jar file.

Second thing is that the command that you have posted in the question does not require those jars to be executable. When you use `-cp`, then the parameters (i.e. **a.jar** etc..)are basically libraries or in other words, when `java` will look for a class file to find definition of a class or a function or whatever for that matter, it will look inside these `jars` if what it is looking for is not part of the java standard library.

Comment: Creating a 'fat Jar' is usually not the way to go.  1) Occasionally it will breach the licensing arrangement for the API. 2) It will always strip out any digital signatures that were included. 3) It removes much of the benefit of auto-update in JWS.  -1