# ClassNotFoundException in MySQL Connector/J

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc, classloader

This has been asked before but I cannot find the answer I need.

1)  Using `Class.forName("com.mysql.java.Driver")` in the eclipse IDE all works well. I load the correct jar (mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar), no exception.

When I create a jar for my app a1.jar and double click the jar, I get the `ClassnotFoundException`.

I created a .bat file in Windows XP with

`java -classpath c:\temp\mysql-connector-java-5.1.20-bin.jar -jar c:\temp\a1.jar` the app statrs with the same exception.

Furthermore using `System.getProperty ("java.class.path")` shows `c:\temp\a1.jar` whilst in the IDE I can see several directories

Comment: can you post the stack trace? how are you sure it's the mySql driver class that is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are executing a file using `-jar`, then any external classpath (either provided on the commandline or the environment) is ignored. It only looks to the `Class-path:` entry in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file. If the MySQL jar isn't specified there, it won't load it.

Comment: Thx.  The class-path was not being copied into META-INF/MANIFEST.MF.  It was in my Manifest.txt. Opening the .jar and your input resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

When you are running an application from the jar then you may need to check the manifest file way of adding the classpath dependencies. Take a look at this [Manifest Classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

Comment: This makes sense. I tried it but nothing changed. I made sure there was a newline in the manifest file.

Comment: Did you bundle the mysql-connector jar inside your jar?

Comment: No, The docs indicate not to. I placed it in the same directory as the jar.I opened the jar and checked the manifest was there and contained the correct jar name.

Answer (score 1):

The driver is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, not `com.mysql.java.Driver`.

You receive the ClassNotFoundException, because there is no `com.mysql.java.Driver` class in the Connector/J library.

Comment: Sorry typo in submission it is jdbc.Driver:  that is why it worked in eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you could do is put all the required libraries in a single file in an executable jar.
The following response may be of great help:

- [eclipse create executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8159427/870248)

Since Eclipse 3.5, you could also use the eclipse wizard to export an executable jar.

Use File > Export... and select Runnable JAR file. The Runnable Jar Export window has a radio button where you can choose to Extract or to Package the required libraries into genratated jar.

[image: Export]
[image: Runnable JAR File Export]

Comment: IMHO it is better to build a correct manifest file and reference the libraries instead of building one über-jar which contains all external dependencies.